# Apache: How do I share one set of files with two different domains?

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I'd like to run my website in two different modes: dev, and test. I currently have the site set up in /var/www/mywebsite.com and working fine. Now I'd like to set up a different url that points to the same files, but has only one difference: apache's setEnv. I want to setEnv APP_ENV test so I can then hit http://test.mywebsite.com/ and read that APP_ENV in PHP. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Apache docs say that virtualhost is a valid context, and that declaring it with no value sets it to empty. Just do this (haven't tested, GL :-)

```
<VirtualHost dev.mysite.xyz:80>
  ...
  SetEnv
  ...
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost test.mysite.xyz:80>
  ...
  SetEnv APP_ENV 
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This is more or less what I ended up doing.  In my particular case it was easier to do this, but use a different port instead of a different subdomain.